# Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port

Tags: arch-linux, audio, kernel-modules, codec

I have installed Arch Linux (x86-64) on a tabled, which is Chuwi Hi12. I have downloaded this sound codec specific for this tabled here:

https://github.com/kernins/linux-chwhi12/tree/master/sound/soc/codecs

I compiled and installed it. The problem is that sounds doesn't play, but a noise that indicates the sound card is working sounds. I don't know if it error is in the code I downloaded or in any step I did. In the system log (dmesg), there is a error that is repeated a lot:

```
Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
```

The complete dmesg out is here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wb3f9l_LW5IuZVtm9Hz7yiq5DQtwIWF-

Sorry for the use of Google Drive, but pastebin doesn't work.

Comment: Same issue with Zorin 12.4 (a Ubuntu Xenial derivative) with *`Linux version 4.15.0-45-generic`*. The machine is a [low-end Mini PC](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07D9YX3W6), and Zorin is fully patched with `dist-upgrade`. The issue appears to be related to Cherry Trail. I suppose that's an Intel code name.